# How to get value inside the subscription in Angular without using async await

Tags: angular

How do you extract the value inside the subscribe on Angular?

I have this code:

```
 async trackingInfo(trackingNumber) {
    const foo = await this.userService
      .trackOrderStatus(trackingNumber)
      .subscribe((status) => {
        console.log(status, 'stat');
        return status;
      });
    console.log(foo, 'grrr');
  }
```

`foo` returns the subscription not the `status` I know there's a way not to use async await but I totally forgot.

Comment: You are already getting the value of observable in subscribe() next callback - `(status) => {console.log(status);}` Just remove async/await. Or please clarify your questions a bit.

Comment: @aRtoo, the idea in Angular is that you **only** subscribe in components (or use pipe async). So, when you subscribe you received the data and can show it. If you subscribe in a class or in service you're enter in problems because you can not "show it". Well you always can subscribe and say to "Angular" that "something has changed" -for this you create a Subject and again in component subscribe to the Subject-, You can also use rxjs operator `tap` to store and create a "cache", but the rule is again: subscribe only in components.

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to something in the subscribe block:

```
status: any;

trackingInfo(trackingNumber) {
    const foo = this.userService
      .trackOrderStatus(trackingNumber)
      .subscribe((status) => {
        console.log(status, 'stat');
        this.status = status;
      });
    console.log(foo, 'grrr');
  }
```

Comment: this is what I did but im getting undefined and I dont know why. this sis called inside the `ngOnInit`

Comment: this is crazy im debugging it and on chrome I can see the values. but on vscode its undefined. on the browser console, when hovering the mouse there's a value showing up. and vscode putting the variable in watch on debugger its undefined. any idea about this?